# Quantum gates in computational basis notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I stumbled upon such notations: $X=|0\rangle\langle1|+|1\rangle\langle0|$ for of logical NOT gate, or $|00\rangle\langle00|+|01\rangle\langle01|+|10\rangle\langle10|+|11\rangle\langle11|$ for 2-qubit indentity.

I am not sure I understand it correctly: does it mean that gate $|0\rangle\langle0|+i|1\rangle\langle1|= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{bmatrix}$?

How would you write SWAP gate in such notation?

Comment: The wikipedia site is fairly explicit: [Swap Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Swap_(S)_gate). But yes, in order to build a matrix representation you pick a basis and an order for the basis states, find the action of the transformation over each one of them and construct the matrix correspondingly.

Comment: I know the matrix representation of SWAP, but would you write alternatively as $|00\rangle\langle 00|+|01\rangle\langle 10|+|10\rangle\langle 01|+|11\rangle\langle 11|$? It's just not common notation in notes on quantum computation and I am not sure if it's equivalent.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes, that seems right.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}$

Lets say, we define our states as $\ket0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\ket{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.
Then, the NOT operation does, $X\ket0 = \ket1$ and $X\ket1 =\ket0$, which can be described by the matrix
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} = \ket0 \bra1 + \ket1 \bra0.$$

Now, if we consider two qubits, the states can be defined as,
$$\ket{00} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\0\\0 \\0 \end{bmatrix},\quad
\ket{01} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\1\\0 \\0 \end{bmatrix},\quad
\ket{10} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0\\1 \\0 \end{bmatrix},\quad
\ket{11} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0\\0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, the SWAP operation $S$ does the following:
$$
S\ket{00} = \ket{00}\\
S\ket{01} = \ket{10}\\
S\ket{10} = \ket{01}\\
\,S\ket{11} = \ket{11}.$$
This is represented by the matrix
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
And if you check that this matrix can be written as,

$$S = |00\rangle\langle00|+|01\rangle\langle10|+|10\rangle\langle01|+|11\rangle\langle11|.$$

So, the answer to your questions are yes.

Comment: You have a couple of typos in the final expression you wrote for $S$. You said yourself that $S |01\rangle = |10\rangle$ and viceversa.

Comment: @secavara: which typos are you referring to?

Comment: @gls already fixed them. It was the final expression for $S$. It's all fine now.